# Fiware Context Broker with entities geolocated

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion

I have a problem in retrieving entities using georeferenced queries.
Use the v2 syntax.

This is my query:

```
GET /v2/entities?georel=near;maxDistance:1000&geometry=point&coords=13.52,43.61
```

and this is my entity:

```
{
    "id": "p1",
    "type": "pm",
    "address": {
        "type": "Text",
        "value": "Via Roma "
    },
    "allowedVehicleType": {
        "type": "Text",
        "value": "car"
    },
    "category": {
        "type": "Text",
        "value": "onstreet"
    },
    "location": {
        "type": "geo:json",
        "value": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [ 13.5094, 43.6246 ]
        }
    },
    "name": {
        "type": "Text",
        "value": "p1"
    },
    "totalSpotNumber": {
        "type": "Number",
        "value": 32
    }
}
```

What is wrong?
I followed the official documentation but I can not get any results as well.
I also tried to reverse the coordinates, but the result does not change.
Any suggestion is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Note that longitude comes before latitude in GeoJSON coordinates, while the `coords` parameters does in the opposite way.

Thus, assuming that your entity is located in Ancona city, I think that using `"coordinates": [ 43.6246, 13.5094 ]` will solve the problem.

Comment: thanks for reply. I tried as you suggest. I reversed the coordinates of all entities as you indicated but the result of the query is still empty. What am I doing wrong? It 'possible that depends on the version of Orion I use?

{ "orion": { "version": "1.0.0", "uptime": "37 d, 8 h, 26 m, 46 s", "git_hash": "8bd2c62366f67596d518607b8d6886bc42ec5d2e", "compile_time": "Tue Mar 29 13:20:18 CEST 2016", "compiled_by": "fermin", "compiled_in": "centollo" } }

thanks, Giuseppe

Comment: Orion 1.0.0 is a bit old. I'd recommend you to upgrade to newest version (Orion 1.5.0 in the moment of writting this) and try again. Please, keep posted your progress.